# How to make Wave Widget Take full Height of Screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [waves package](https://github.com/i-protoss/wave) and I wanna set height full screen I try many ways but not work this is out put

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY54K.png)

and this is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    left: true,
    top: true,
    right: true,
    bottom: true,
    minimum: EdgeInsets.zero,
    maintainBottomViewPadding: false,
    child: Container(
      child: Expanded(
        child: WaveWidget(
          config: CustomConfig(
            gradients: [
              [
                Color.fromRGBO(72, 74, 126, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(125, 170, 206, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(184, 189, 245, 0.7)
              ],
              [
                Color.fromRGBO(72, 74, 126, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(125, 170, 206, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(172, 182, 219, 0.7)
              ],
              [
                Color.fromRGBO(72, 73, 126, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(125, 170, 206, 1),
                Color.fromRGBO(190, 238, 246, 0.7)
              ],
            ],
            durations: [19440, 10800, 6000],
            heightPercentages: [0.03, 0.01, 0.02],
            blur: MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.solid, 10),
            gradientBegin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            gradientEnd: Alignment.topCenter,
          ),
          size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
          waveAmplitude: 14,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

how can set height full of screen ? I wanna first time height set full screen and after some times set height 0 but not set full screen

Comment: Try removing SafeArea

Comment: @Josteve I tried but it did not work

Comment: @parham I have never used that plugin but from what I saw on their examples there is always a top margin, so I don't think you can do anything about it.